# Modifying Create New

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which displays a list of courses. I want to link the user to a create new view. The create new view should be for the specific course the user has chosen. But right now the courses are displayed in a drop down list. I don't want the user to have to choose a course again.

I have an Index view which list courses (ex. history, maths..). When the course is chosen it takes it to the create new view. I want to modify the view so that user fill the application for a specific course.

---

```
@Html.ActionLink("Choose", "ChooseCorse", "FillCourse", new { id = item.idCourse }, null)
```

Now I'm using an ActionLink to link the user to the create new view and take the id of the course, but it's where I get stuck. How do I display the course chosen and make sure it's saved in the database?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChooseCourse(int? id)
 {
   //For the dropdow list
   ViewBag.idCourse = new SelectList(db.tbCourses,"idCourse","Name",fillCourse.idCourse);
   return View();
 }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult ChooseCourse (tbFillCourse fillCourse)
    {
       if(!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           return View();
        }

        else
         {
            db.tbFillCourses.Add(fillCourse);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
          }

      }
```

---

This is my first time using the site so if I need to provide more or have done something wrong please correct me.

Comment: So is this all working except that the `Create` view does not pick the default course? I don't see how it is working because my understanding is that `ActionLink` calls the `HttpGet` method, but your method just returns a drop down - nothing else - is that right? It's not clear exactly what you have now and what is not functioning.

Comment: As far as I can tell your ActionLink doesn't set a value for `fillCourse` (whatever that is), which is a problem for two reasons: 1. It's not an optional (nullable) method parameter; 2. You use it in your `SelectList` function

Answer (score -1):

Does this work?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ChooseCourse(int? id)
 {
   //For the dropdown list
   ViewBag.idCourse = new SelectList(db.tbCourses,"idCourse","Name",id);
   return View();
 }
```

I don't know what the parameter `tbFillCourse fillCourse` is meant to be doing, but;

1. You aren't passing anything to it, so it should actually fail because it's not an optional parameter as far as I can tell
2. You're using it as the default value when populating the drop down

It seems like all the `HttpGet` does is populates a drop down - it doesn't return a view at all.

I suggest you use a breakpoint to step through and inspect the parameter values

Comment: The paramater tbFillCourse fillCourse is my mistake. Id does return a view but the view now displays a dropdown list which I don't need.

Comment: Your response is very unclear. `id` is an `int` - it can't return a view. Do you mean the `ChooseCourse` method returns a view? In your sample code it doesn't return anything (there is nothing between the brackets in `return View();`) . I suggest you take a look at the automatically generated `Create` method and just alter that. By _now displays a dropdown list which I don't need_ do you mean you just want to display a label for the course? Please take the time to be clear in your requirements.